# how to connect to flutter app from dart devTools

Tags: flutter, dart

when i run "flutter pub global run devtools"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfNuN.png)

where i can find  **URL to a running Dart or Flutter application.** to connect to??

Answer (score 3):

a year behind but the documentation didn't help me in my case beings I was running the app from VS Code.

If you are running from the terminal, it will say something like `An Observatory debugger and profiler on iPhone X is available at: http://127.0.0.1:50976/Swm0bjIe0ks=/`. You then just put that url (`http://127.0.0.1:50976/Swm0bjIe0ks=/`) in the dev tools 'connect to a running app' text field and press connect.

If you are running from VS Code, and I can only assume most other text editors/IDE's, you can run `flutter attach` which will bring up the same message as above with the url holding your builds security token.
Again, plop that in and you're plop to go

Comment: `flutter attach` is what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the Dart documentation on how to do that via the link below:

https://dart.dev/tools/dart-devtools